# Is there any possibility to avoid multiple ../ when we are importing a function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, path, serverless

I want to avoid this thing at importing a function

```
const ApiError = require('../../../../classes/ErrorClass');
```

Is any possibility to use,I don't know Ex:

```
require('mypath/ErrorClass')
```

If I have 11 imports I don't want to have something like this

```
const ApiError = require('../../../../classes/ErrorClass');
const ex= require('../../../classes/ApiClass');
const ex1= require('../../../../utils/utils');
const ex2= require('../../../etc/etc');
const ex3= require('../../../../../etc/etc');
const ex4= require('../../../../etc/etc');
const ex5= require('../../../../etc/etc');
const ex6= require('../../../../etc/etc');
```

Thank you!

Comment: Why is everything being assigned to the same variable? Your code doesn't make much sense.

Comment: It's just an example

Comment: `path.dirname(require.main.filename)` returns always the directory of the main-file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do it with `package.json`.
Imagine you have the following structure:

```
my-app/
├─ src/
│  ├─ index.js
│  ├─ node_modules/
│  ├─ dir/
│  │  ├─ nested/
│  │  │  ├─ nestedMod.js
│  ├─ function/
│  │  ├─ myMod.js
│  │  ├─ myMod3.js
│  │  ├─ myMod2.js
├─ package.json
```

You have to add the `imports` field in `package.json`

```json
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "imports": {
    "#nestedMod": "./src/dir/nested/nestedMod.js",
    "#myFunc": "./src/function/myMod.js",
    "#myFunc2": "./src/function/myMod2.js",
    "#myFuncs/*": "./src/function/*.js"
  }
}
```

then you can do:

```
const nestedMod = require('#nestedMod')
const myFunc = require('#myFunc')
const myFunc2 = require('#myFunc2')
const myFunc3 = require('#myFuncs/myMod3')
```

P.S.: Only works in Node

Answer (score 0):

Since there's no insight on your configuration, I'll try to provide some different solutions here.

**Webpack**

If you're using webpack, you could use an alias config for the resolve property to create a mapping between your actual path the what you want to call it. It would look something like this:

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      Components: path.resolve(__dirname, '/path/to/function') 
    }
  }
}
```

Check the [resolve chapter](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/) form webpack docs for more info.

**Typescript**

While using typescript, you could specify the `baseUrl` property in the `tsconfig.json`, which would allow you to specify every import relative to the path you specified there. Let's say you have this path: `'../../../../classes/ErrorClass'`, which, expanded, could look like: `src/some/folder/structure/classes/ErrorClass`. After the config, this could look like this `classes/ErrorClass`, if the `baseUrl` is configured to `src/some/folder/structure`.

Answer (score -1):

you would want to use a built-in variable node provided `__dirname` to have the app root directory

say you have this directory

```
myapp/
├─ utils/
│  ├─ main.js
├─ lib/
│  ├─ mylib.js
├─ node_modules/
```

so,
main.js:

```js
const mylib = require(__dirname + '/lib/mylib')
```

Comment: `__dirname` is the directory of the current file, not the root directory.